# sorting objects into an array of elements and an array with several elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, iteration

I have to sort a list of students, depending on the specialty they applied to.

My variabile for array in object is `String [] specializations;`

The objects I introduced look like this:

`x.add (new Students ("Tudorache1", "Marinel", new String [] {"Programmer", "WEB"}, 12, 24, 2020));`

`x.add (new Students ("Tudorache7", "Marinel2", new String [] {"Operator", "WEB", "Developer"}, 12, 24, 2021));`

`x.add (new Students ("Tudorache3", "Marinel3", new String [] {"Constructor", "Accountant", "Secretary"}, 12, 24, 2018));`

How can I sort by iteration to get:

WEB
Tudorache1
Tudorache7

Programmer
Tudorache1

Operator
Tudorache7

Developer
Tudorache7

Constructor
Tudorache3

Accountant
Tudorache3

Secretary
Tudorache3

Comment: HINT: a `Map<String, List<String>>`, where each `String` key is a specialization, and the corresponding `List<String>` value is a list of all the students who applied to that specialty.

Answer (score 0):

List of Students is not good data structure for such sorting.
For example you can iterate thru specializations. Print specialization, then run thru x and print student's name if his specialization contain specialization. It is not optimal way but possible.

Answer (score 0):

The given list of `Students` should be converted into a map of specializations to the list of the first field of `Students` class (let's assume this field is `lastName`).  Then the map may be converted into array of string arrays.

This can be resolved using Java Stream API:

```java
public static Map<String, List<String>> mapSpecToNames(List<Students> students) {
    return students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> Arrays.stream(student.getSpecializations())
                                      .map(spec -> Arrays.asList(spec, student.getLastName()))
            ) // Stream<List<String>>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                pair -> pair.get(0), // specialization is a key
                LinkedHashMap::new,  // keep insertion order
                Collectors.mapping(
                    pair -> pair.get(1), Collectors.toList() // List<String> of names
                )
    ));
}

public String[][] mapToArray(List<Students> students) {
    return mapSpecToNames(students)
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> Stream.concat(
                    Stream.of(e.getKey()), 
                    e.getValue().stream()
                )
                .toArray(String[]::new)
            )
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

Test

```
List<Students> students = Arrays.asList(
    new Students ("Tudorache1", "Marinel", new String [] {"WEB", "Programmer"}, 12, 24, 2020),
    new Students ("Tudorache7", "Marine2", new String [] {"Operator", "WEB", "Developer"}, 12, 24, 2020),
    new Students ("Tudorache3", "Marine3", new String [] {"Constructor", "Accountant", "Secretary"}, 12, 24, 2020)
);

String[][] result = mapToArray(students);
        
Arrays.stream(result)
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[WEB, Tudorache1, Tudorache7]
[Programmer, Tudorache1]
[Operator, Tudorache7]
[Developer, Tudorache7]
[Constructor, Tudorache3]
[Accountant, Tudorache3]
[Secretary, Tudorache3]
```